# How can I find all files I do not have write access to in specific folder?

Tags: files, permissions, find

How can I find all files I can not write to?

Would be good if it takes standard permissions and acls into account.

Is there an "easy" way or do I have to parse the permissions myself?

Comment: should it consider only files owned by the current user(you)?

Comment: Should consider all files I cannot write to

Comment: it's too simple `find . -type f ! -writable`

Comment: Roman's answer works. It wouldn't contain files of which Alex is the owner because that would mean that he can write to them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
find . ! -writable
```

the command `find` returns a list of files, `-writable` filters only the ones you have write permission to, and the `!` inverts the filter.

You can add `-type f` if you want to ignore the directories and other 'special files'.

Comment: And add -user <username/userid> if you want to restrict this to a specific user.

Comment: Note that it misses the ones that are in directories you don't have search or read access to.

Comment: It should also be noted that if you own the file, you can always give yourself write permission to it. And if you have write permission to the directory the file is in, you can always replace the file with another one.

Comment: is `! ...` a substitution?

Comment: @cat It's `find` syntax, but the man page notes "*This character will also usually need protection from interpretation by the shell.*" If you're using GNU `find`, you can also use `-not`.

Comment: Yeah `-not` seems a lot safer than `!`.

Answer (score 3):

On non-Linux systems and systems without GNU `find`, the following is likely to give the same output as `find . -type f ! -writable`, it does however not take secondary groups into account.

```
myname=$( id -un )
mygroup=$( id -gn )

find . -type f '(' \
       '('   -user "$myname"                     ! -perm -u=w ')' -o \
       '(' ! -user "$myname"   -group "$mygroup" ! -perm -g=w ')' -o \
       '(' ! -user "$myname" ! -group "$mygroup" ! -perm -o=w ')' ')'
```

The four tests in order:

1. Is it a regular file?
2. Is it a file that I own but that I don't have write permissions to?
3. Is it a file that I don't own, but that belongs to my group, and that I don't have group write permissions to?
4. Is it a file that I don't own and that does not belong to my group, and that I don't have general ("other") write permissions to?

The benefit of this is that you may substitute in another user's name and group, which I don't think GNU `find`'s `-writable` allows you to do.

---

The same command but with the logic written in AND form:

```
find . -type f \
    ! '('   -user "$myname"                     -perm -u=w ')' \
    ! '(' ! -user "$myname"   -group "$mygroup" -perm -g=w ')' \
    ! '(' ! -user "$myname" ! -group "$mygroup" -perm -o=w ')'
```

Comment: What does the `o` in `-o=w` mean exactly?  I'm having trouble finding it in the manpage. I'm assuming `other` (i.e. world writable). I was expecting it to be `-a=w` (to be consistent with `chmod a+w` but I have a feeling my understanding is wrong).